# Max and min in many variables (Lagrange multipliers)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have doubts for what concerns the end of this exercise. I have the function $f(x, y, z) = x$ and I have to find min and max subject to the constraints $x^2+y^2+z^2 = \frac{5}{2}$ and $y + z = 1$.

I calculated the Jacobian matrix of the constraints and I found it has maximum rank of $2$, unless $x = y = z = 0$ thought this point doesn't nullify the constraints, hence they are regular. Thence the Lagrangian reads

$$L(x, y, z, \lambda, \mu) = x - \lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-5/2) - \mu(y+z-1)$$

After a short algebra I found two solutions:

$$(\sqrt{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \qquad \text{for} \quad \lambda = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}, \quad \mu = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
$$(-\sqrt{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \qquad \text{for} \quad \lambda = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}, \quad \mu = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

*Question: I have been told that the sign of the multiplier determines if I found a max ($\lambda > 0$ or a min ($\lambda < 0$). I still did not really understand this well, but in any case how would I declare which of these is the max and which is the min?

The function over those points (where $y$ and $z$ are basically useless for $f$) is the same and it is $\sqrt{2}$.

Can you please help me in understanding how this work?

Comment: Without stronger hypotheses, we cannot directly predict the type of critical point from the sign of $\lambda$. The [first example here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lagrange_multiplier#Example_1) has max for $\lambda <0$ and min for $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: Double check if your second solution is correct. Using the values you currently have for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in the second solution, the partial of $L$ w.r.t. $x$ is: $$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 1 +x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, $$ and will not be zero for $x=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @SammyBlack Actually we use $L$ as $f - \lambda g$, and hence in this case positive $\lambda$ gives indeed the max, and vice versa...

Comment: examples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4844606/532409 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1487134/532409 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3888951/532409 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2360063/532409

Answer (score 0):

A couple of remarks, that hopefully are able to shed some light on your question(s)

- I would strongly advise against using the sign of the Lagrange multiplier to check if its a minimum or maximum. Lets say you have the constraint $x=y+2$. Would you use $g=y-x+2$ or $g=x-y-2$?
- You made a mistake with your second solution, it should read $(-\sqrt{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.
- If you really want to make sure if you are dealing with a minimum, maximum or saddle you need to check the Hessian of the Lagrangian and its definiteness. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test
- In your case the first solution $(\sqrt{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is the desired maximum and $(-\sqrt{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is the desired minimum.

Comment: Actually we use $L$ as $f - \lambda g$, and hence in this case positive $\lambda$ gives indeed the max, and vice versa...

Comment: I added a small example that hopefully sheds some more light on the issue.